is it possible to restore multiple whatsapp backups
One friend just deleted by mistake a document on Whatsapp and I was thinking to recover it by doing the followings:

create an additional backup with the latests chats/files/photos (special backup, see bellow)
uninstall and reinstall Whatsapp but restore the default automatically created backup
recover the deleted file (place it somewhere safe)
uninstall and reinstall Whatsapp, but, this time, restore the backup from step 1 with the latest things

Now my questions:

Can I do multiple backups and store them along with the automatically created backup on GoogleDrive?
Can I select which backup to restore ... so that I can do the above flow?
What sort of backups should I do so that all files are included (photos, documents, videos, etc)

(By default Whatsapp automatically creates backups from time to time and store them on Google Drive. On my Google Drive account there is just one backup - the latest. The thing is I don't want to interfere with the default/automatic mechanism and loose the default Whatsapp backup.)
Why I need this additional backups? Since the time the automatic backup was performed, my friend received other messages/files and we don't want to loose them by restoring the older backup from Google Drive. That's why I propose the above time-traveling to restore the lost file, but return to present time and have all things back to normal

This question is similar to: WhatsApp: incremental backup possible?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It may not be an exact duplicate but in essence you can't selectively backup by date or person. When you restore a backup, existing data is overwritten//Putting in another way you are probably looking at merging two Whatsapp data bases, which was possible at one point of time for rooted devices. There is a thread on XDA on this but I did recall that the said method didn't work at a later point of time
